# Automatically generated assembly code for "Hello World!" does not build on Netbeans 8.1 on Windows 10

Tags: netbeans, assembly, disassembly

I am unable to build and run assembly code on Netbeans 8.1. I am however able to properly build and run my C code.

The details of my C-based tools are as follows:

[image]

I first chose to develop a C application:

[image]

I created a project called `Assembly`:

[image]

I tried to replicate the steps given in [Darius' link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToCreate64-BitC/C++WindowsProgramWithNetBeans#Setting_up_the_Build_Tools_in_NetBeans). I had a `main.c` file in which I typed `printf("Hello World\n");` and it worked.

[image]

I then created `main.s` by typing `gcc -S main.c` in the Windows command prompt and main.s was created. I tried to build it, but it failed with the following output:

```
cd 'C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AssemblyProject\Assembly_test'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AssemblyProject/Assembly_test'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/assembly_test.exe
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/XXXX /Documents/NetBeansProjects/AssemblyProject/Assembly_test'

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 533ms)
cd 'C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\NetBeansProjects\AssemblyProject\Assembly_test'
C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AssemblyProject/Assembly_test'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/assembly_test.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AssemblyProject/Assembly_test'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
as  -g -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o main.s
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows
gcc     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/assembly_test build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:21:(.stab+0x14): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:23:(.stab+0x20): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x2c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x38): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x44): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x50): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x5c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x68): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x74): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x80): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.text'
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o:main.s:26:(.stab+0x8c): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63: dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/assembly_test.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/XXXX
/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AssemblyProject/Assembly_test'
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: .build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/XXXX/Documents/NetBeansProjects/AssemblyProject/Assembly_test'
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:40: .build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

The details of my assembler are as follows:

```
C:\Users\XXXXX>as --version

GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.29.1.20171006 
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc. 
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of 
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later. 
This program has absolutely no warranty. 
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-pc-cygwin'.
```

EDIT:

Upon opening Cygwin's command prompt and running the commands for compiling and running programs, I observed that I could run both my assembly and C codes.

[image]

EDIT:

I created a new project, used `gcc -S main.c` to create the file `main.s` and it  failed to build on Netbeans (It failed with the same errors about truncation). **I find it even more baffling that I can use the command `gcc main.s -o MAIN`on the Windows Command Prompt and create an executable (MAIN.exe) which works perfectly (from the command line)**. 
So this shows that my automatically generated assembly code fails to build ONLY in my Netbeans environment.

**Can someone please explain the cause of this behavior?**

Additionally, Ramhound indicated that my makefile is not pointing to the correct location. As shown in the first picture of this question, I am selecting the project option which automatically creates its own makefile. Moreover, the makefile allows my C code to build and run perfectly. The problem arises only when I try to build my assembly programs on Netbeans. **I looked over Darius' link and nothing was said about modifying the makefile JUST for assembly programs.**

Comment: I'm assuming you already followed the instructions here http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToCreate64-BitC/C++WindowsProgramWithNetBeans ?

Comment: @Darius I had not followed the instructions in your link. I tried following the assembly-based instructions in your link but when I created `main.S` and tried to build it, it failed.

Comment: @Darius My C code builds properly though.

Comment: Please let me know why my question has been down-voted.

Comment: You may get better answers for this question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: If you compile the code from within a Cygwin prompt does it work?  You should edit your question to include this vital information.  I suspect the problem is that Netbeans has a problem with the Cygwin executables.  I won't know if that is the case unless I know if the code will compile within a Cygwin prompt.

Comment: @Ramhound I included snippets from Cygwin's command in my question. Is this what you wanted to see?

Comment: @Ramhound I was unsure of compiling my assembly code so I was typing random commands. `main.s` was already in my folder and when I typed `gcc main.s -o MAIN`, I obtained an executable called `MAIN.exe` and it ran successfully as you can see in my last picture.

Comment: Well based on the output you provided, and the fact you proved gcc could indeed compile the code, your makefile configuration is incorrect.  *I am guessing you didn't modify it to point to where things were on your system.*  I know`../build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows` is the proper location for gcc exectuable.

Comment: @Ramhound The makefile was automatically generated by Netbeans (I outlined all the steps I took to create my Netbeans Project). How can I fix it? Should I also post my makefile here?

Comment: Based on the output, it appears your makefile, is pointing to the incorrect location.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I point it to the correct location?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77872/discussion-between-a-sid-and-ramhound).

Comment: I had downloaded netbeans and followed the instructions in the wiki I posted - and that worked perfectly. My suggestion is take heed of Ramhound's suggestion and check. Maybe start over with a fresh Project (so no random makefile dependencies). Don't edit your existing one, just start over fresh and see if it works out for you. Once you got a working environment, then add your codes as needed. Good luck. Note: I'm using MSYS2 as opposed to Cygwin (as that is what the wiki recommended) but I don't believe that will cause any issue as long as you got all the correct executables.

Comment: @Darius I created a fresh project and I am still getting errors about truncation. **I can build and run my C code perfectly on Netbeans**. The problem only arises when I try to build my assembly code. **I also find it baffling that I can create an executable from the windows command prompt which works perfectly**. The issue occurs only when I try to build my assembly code on Netbeans.

Comment: Additionally, If there are errors in my question, please point them out to me and I shall try to rectify them. Otherwise, I shall appreciate it if someone removes the down-votes.

Comment: @Ramhound  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Darius Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot of part of `main.s` doesn't show any use of 32-bit absolute addressing.  Your error message includes `main.s:21:(.stab+0x14): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against`.text'`, but the instruction on line 21 is a RIP-relative LEA, so it should use an x86_64_PC32 relocation.

Your gcc was making position-independent code.

But the error mentions `.stab`, so maybe the problem is an obsolete debug format using 32-bit absolute addresses.  Perhaps you have Netbeans set to compile/assemble with `-gstabs` or something.  On ELF targets, the default format for `-g` is DWARF, but IDK about Windows.

Anyway, test this theory by turning off debug symbols in Netbeans, and see if the error goes away.  If so, you know that generating the debug info was the problem.

Comment: You maybe interested in the feedback I left in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77872/).

Comment: After I removed `-g` from my code and clicked on the "Clean and Build" option, the code built successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly you're trying to run uses Linux system calls, and cannot be run on a Windows system.

Windows does not have a stable system call interface, so programming it with pure assembly is inadvisable.

Comment: I still should be able to build code in the way outlined in Darius' link. However, when I try to do that I get errors that look like this:  `relocation
  truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against.text'`. How can I resolve these errors?

Comment: Build it as a 32-bit executable, or use 64-bit instructions. Right now you're trying to build a 64-bit executable with 32-bit instructions, which wouldn't work even on a Linux system.

Comment: I get these errors when I build the assembly code by following the instruction's in [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToCreate64-BitC/C++WindowsProgramWithNetBeans) link. I can build and run the "Hello World" `C` code but when I type `gcc -S main.c` an assembly file called `main.s` gets generated but it does not build when I try to build it.

Comment: The assembly code was automatically generated by the assembler and was derived from a properly working C code. Why should it not build properly when I have an assembler installed in my system?

Comment: @a_sid I find that difficult to believe. The code you've shown us is **word for word** a standard Linux assembly tutorial. No C compiler would ever emit this code.

Comment: I am not talking about the code I have shown. I am talking about the code that was **automatically generated** when I typed `gcc -S main.c` on the command prompt in the appropriate folder. The error messages regarding truncation are for the automatically generated code and NOT for the code posted in my question.

Comment: I edited my question to direct the reader's attention to the source of the errors.